# Current in a cylinder moving with uniform velocity

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, electricity

> [image]

This question might seem silly. I solved this question in the following way. Although, The answer I got from this method is correct but I still have a conceptual doubt in my solution.
[image]
I have put $\frac{dx}{dt}=v$ but here $dx$ is just signifying the length of the small element I took. So how can I put this equal to the velocity of the cylinder. According to me when the cylinder moves forward, $dx$ element must also move forward so $dx$ must remain constant. 
Where am I wrong? If this solution is wrong, please tell the correct way to solve this question.

Comment: You have surface charge density and not linear chare density. It is a cylinder, not a thin wire. The formula for electric field is not appropriate for your problem.

Comment: no. the formula is correct. if you convert the surface charge density into linear charge density, you will get the same relation as we got for a line charge

Comment: Yes, you are right. And dx here is the witdth of the cylindrical ring that passes any point along the axis during the time dt. So you have dx=vdt. To calculate the charge on this ring you use the area of the ring which depends on dx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. I Think this is a good question, because you have arrived at the right answer but do not feel confidence in your methodology. So well dome so far!
2. I think you are right to feel uneasy about the method, because there are two different *x*-coordinates involved, in principle. The first *dx* is an increment in a coordinate system fixed in the cylinder (separation of two points  A and B along the cylinder axis); the second dx is an increment in a coordinate fixed in the laboratory (motion of one fixed point C in a time delta *t*). So at the very least you are recycling a symbol without re-defining it. It turns out to be benign because you are in effect choosing the point C to be A at time *t=0*, and the time delta *t* to be the time it takes A to arrive the point occupied by B at *t=0*.
3. As to the point raised by nasu, that depends how you are conceptualising the symbol lambda. I read it as the charge per unit length, which is the circumference times the charge per unit area, and in the equation for *E* you are dividing put the circumference again, to get the surface charge and hence *E*.But nasu read it as a line cherge, that is zero cross-section, which is indeed geometrically wrong.

So one message is: the words to describe the symbols are really important!